# In-house electrical fast transients (EFT) test

Tags: emc, esd, transient

I am trying to simulate  electrical fast transients (EFT) in order to see if our device is compliant. I am aware that the test that I am conducting is not the most accurate; since we are still in the design phase we just want to see if we are on the right track and do not have any major issues with the design.

My idea is the following:

I will be using an ESD gun (calibrated) and injecting a disturbance into a coaxial cable (low insertion loss.) The coaxial cable is very close distance-wise to our RS485 cable in order to get the best coupling between both cables. I want to measure the pulse that we are injecting and gauge the level of disturbance by measuring it using an oscilloscope.

[image]

My real setup looks like this:

[image]

Could someone point out why I can't see any pulse on the oscilloscope?

Comment: I assume that the scope probe was actually connected to a conductor during the test (photo shows it disconnected.) Validate the probe/input is working via the test signal source.  Any idea how much current the ESD gun is capable of?  Could try adding a resistor from coax to ground, but then capacitive coupling effects will dominate.  The grey/green mat also could be the ESD type; that will tend to shunt high voltages to ground.  Try placing the cables on a known-insulative surface.

Comment: That is a good point, Indeed in the picture the probe was disconnected, but I had it connected to the RS485 cable earlier. What would be the benefit of adding a resistor to the coax?

Comment: Adding a resistor should definitely show a pulse, if only because of capacitive effects.  Since there has been no pulse yet, this would rule out the scope probe/channel being defective, and the mat "absorbing" all of the pulse.  Only to prove everything is working.

Comment: Unfortunately I still cannot see a pulse...